# How to print postgres table output so it can distinguish between empty string and null

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, sql-null

is there a way to configure psql or to pass in some parameter when doing query, to print out different value for null and for empty string? Currently it shows empty for both.

For example, i have a table with this content:

```
adventure=# select * from account
adventure-# ;
 user_id | username | password | email |         created_on         |         last_login         
---------+----------+----------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------
       1 |          |          |       | 2020-04-07 10:30:08.836098 | 2020-04-07 10:30:08.836098
(1 row)
```

With this, I cannot tell if username is empty string or a null. In this case, username is null, but password is empty string.

I tried using `\x on`, but it's the same thing.

Of course, i could do some coalescing, but that's a bit too much if i need to do it for every column.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In `psql` you can do that with the configuration option `null` which can be changed using `\pset`

```
postgres=# \pset null '<null>'
Null display is "<null>".
postgres=# select null as c1, '' as c2;
   c1   | c2
--------+----
 <null> |
```

If you want that option permanently, you can put the `\pset` command into [.psqlrc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce()` to replace the `NULL` value with something else:

```
select coalesce(username, '<null user>') as username,
       coalesce(password, '<null password>') as password
```

Or, if you want to include a third value for empty strings, use `case`:

```
select (case when username is null then '<null user>'
             when username = '' then '<empty user>'
             else username
        end)
```

Of course, if a password were `<null password>'` then it would look like the `NULL` value.

Or, you can enclose the values in quotes:

```
select '"' || username || '"' as username
```

The `||` operator returns `NULL` if the value is `NULL`.

Comment: Yeah i mentioned that i can do that, but in cases where I have a lot of these, I would like to just do `select *`. Also, i think this would potentially be an issue for non-varchar field types, like a date.